# How to completely separated DOM manipulation from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, dom, model-view-controller

I have to create a website for a friend of mine using PHP. It is basically an online store.

I want to use new features of HTML5, CSS3, jQuery and other JS libraries.
And I want to keep all the document generation and manipulation separate from PHP.

I have done a lot of searching on Google. People come up with MVC architecture. And that's all good.
But the problem is in all the examples or tutorials that I found; people retrieve the data from the SQL based databases, and then `echo` or `print` it to generate html, or use some ORM classes to display it. I don't know much about ORM or PHP frameworks.

I have always made pet projects, small websites, nothing like this medium-sized Store.

The way I understand the MVC architecture is this:

```
**Model:** Basic purpose is to save and retrieve data from the databases.
**Controller:** Do some operations on the data to either store them using Model, or do some operations on the retrieved data (again using the Model), to be passed to the View.
**View:** This is used to display the user the content.
```

What I want to do is do **almost ZERO html generation using PHP**.
Instead I was thinking of a approach in which :
*Model is used for database handling only.* 
Controller is used to convert that data into JSON objects, and make those JSON objects available to the appropriate Views.
Then using JavaScript I will do the DOM Manipulations according to the JSON objects.

Is this approach any good ? If yes how to do it (especially the part of converting the data retrieved from database to JSON objects).

If you can provide me with a better approach where I won't have to do generate html using PHP, and use PHP for front-end as less as possible.

I am doing all the front-end stuff which the user is gonna see. My friend will be doing all the database handling. I don't wanna get involved in the PHP part, and if it is mandatory (i.e. there is no way-out) then as little as possible.

Please provide me with some solution. In desperate need here.

**EDIT:** I am especially talking about `echo` and `print` commands. I would like to have a fresh slate to work on instead of getting the html creation mixed with PHP and JavaScript. 
If NOT using these commands is not suggested based on the fact that the user may be on mobile device, or have JavaScript turned off. Then is it possible to have a simple looking website with all the data displayed if JavaScript is turned off; and if it's not turned off then remove all those elements from the DOM and make a fresh DOM with JavaScript. However the main hindrance to this is converting the data retrieved from database to JSON object so that it can be used by the JavaScript.

I don't think this is possible, but is there some way in which PHP variables can be directly used by JavaScript ?

Comment: Um...the DOM is on the client (unless you're using special-purpose DOM-on-server libs, which doesn't seem to be the case). PHP is on the server. How exactly are you *not* completely separating the DOM manipulation from PHP?!

Comment: PHP does not manipulate the DOM. It just defines it's initial structure. Your approach will have many, many problems. What if javascript is disabled or the client is a mobile device with low specs? If you are really planning on creating a online store take some FOSS e-commerce package and work with that. It will save you a lot of headaches and you might learn a thing or two along the way.

Comment: [PHP's DOM stuff is built-in](http://www.php.net/book.dom). Using this to combine document fragments in an organized way instead of grinding out HTML in the normal way can actually be quite nice.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
From what I have seen in the tutorials. People always use print or echo to display something on the page.
something like this `<?php echo "Hello World";?>` or `<?php $foo = "foobar"; echo "foo is $foo"; ?>`
We can extend the example assuming that the data in the variable is retrieved from a database.
the echo statement creates a DOM element on the webpage. I want to exclude any `echo` or `print` statements from the PHP code and instead convert the data retrieved from databases into a JSON object, which can then be further accessed by JavaScript.

Comment: @Ishan, right, I actually prefer using the DOM API through PHP rather than doing that as much as possible, but it's not a very popular approach I guess. But print/echo really isn't DOM manipulation, so your question is kind of confusing.

Comment: @Ishan: Then you want to separate PHP from *HTML generation*, not the DOM.

Comment: @DaggNabbit
I guess instead of using DOM Manipulation I should have wrote, not to generate any HTML code for the body, just the header tag, which contains all of my JavaScript links.

Comment: @Ishan I think if you replace "DOM" with "document" in your question it will be more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does never manipulate the DOM, the DOM is purely client side, while php is purely server-side. PHP can generate HTML, which will be sent to the client, and processed to a DOM by the clients browser.

If you want to (nearly) completely split it in two parts, you could split it into an API server (php & database) which will provide a RESTful JSON-API and a content server, which will provide your static HTML, CSS and Javascript files.

The Javascript on the content server will connect to the API server with AJAX get and post requests to retrieve and send data to the database.

Comment: This is not really true. PHP has all of the usual DOM manipulation functions, and can process documents using the DOM before sending them to the client.

Comment: it can process the html code, but the DOM is built by the browser, parsing the HTML, DOM manipulation is done, after this the DOM was created, so PHP will not be able to manipulate the DOM, after the response was sent

Comment: "after the response is sent" != "never." The problem is the idea that "the DOM is purely client side," this is not true.

Comment: @bbuecherl: There are lots of DOM libraries for server-side use.

Comment: but the DOM is build by the Browser, after the response was sent successfully, and the last bit was received (in TCP model, this means, the connection is closed). Now the DOM is created, displayed and fires the onload event.

Comment: @bbuecherl: *"but the DOM is build by the Browser"* No, the DOM is built by something that knows how to build a DOM. Browsers know how to do that, but there are also lots of libraries, including server-side ones (like [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)), that know how to do that. But this is all off-topic, the OP doesn't really mean "DOM," he means "HTML generation."

Comment: ...including the standard DOM API, as spec'd, shipping with stock PHP.

Comment: ok, could you please give me a link, where i can read more about the DOM lifecycle and possibly how php can modify the DOM after the browser triggeres onload? (which in my eyes is DOM manipulation)

Comment: . <----- the point | ---------> you

Comment: @bbuecherl This is exactly what I am looking for. Completely separating PHP and Database on one server, while providing static HTML, CSS and JavaScript from another server. You got exactly to my point. Can you please refer me to articles/tutorials/videos/anything which will teach me how to implement a RESTful JSON-API and a content server. I will be very thankful for this help.

Comment: @Ishan just look for AJAX tutorials on google (first result: http://html.net/tutorials/javascript/lesson21.php ) but to clarify: the API will be implemented on the API server (php), you just need to call the right routes with ajax.
RESTful API with PHP: http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's entirely possible to do what you're describing. You'd use static HTML files for the basic page setup, the usual CSS and images and such, and your PHP would **only** be used to generate JSON to return to the client and get used by JavaScript. So for instance:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="theTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr><em>Loading...</em></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="yourscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`yourscript.js`:

```
getDataViaAjax("data.php", function(data) {
    var table = document.getElementById("theTable");
    // ...fill in the table using the information from `data`...
});
```

`data.php`:

```
<?php
    // Get data from somewhere
    // ...

    // Output it
    echo json_encode($theData);
?>
```

Obviously the table there is just an example. You'd probably have much more static content, and a few places where you wanted to add dynamic content.

This is a perfectly feasible approach, and the separation of concerns helps as the team expands.

However, note that if you do this, any page that has content from the DB will result in *two* HTTP requests to the server (one to load the HTML, the other — which won't start until after the first one is at least partially finished — to load the data) rather than one. In general, the goal is to minimize HTTP requests. So there are trade-offs.

> I don't think this is possible, but is there some way in which PHP variables can be directly used by JavaScript ?

Correct, that's not possible. There are frameworks like [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) (that one isn't PHP-based) that handle the middle layer for you, though, and make it seem a lot like that's happening.

You can also look at tools like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) and [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) that can bind your JavaScript data objects to DOM elements, saving you a huge amount of manual update code, or even just things like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) that render templated stuff for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a client-side [template engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29), where the document is built  client-side using ajax queries. The ones I have heard good things about are Handlebars and Mustache, though I'm sure there are others to choose from.

But even with such a solution, I imagine that some amount of server-side HTML needs to be output to "prime the pump", in which case, you would want to consider a server-side template engine like Smarty or whatever the latest-and-greatest equivalent is. With a server-side template engine, you would write the templates as standalone files (like .tpl for Smarty) and PHP would consume the template as an object and then pass in any unique variables for the template via the template-engine's methods and then you would call the display method for the template.

In either scenario (or a combination of both) you are separating your final HTML output from PHP so that PHP is interacting with the templates rather than doing plain `echo "<div>This looks so Web 1.0</div>";` which I think is what you are trying to avoid.